# Random CSS class/id name using PHP

Tags: php, css, random

I am generating random ID's for 2 divs, and I would like to use those randomly generated names in CSS too, as now I have to use inline styles.

Also, I don't want to use separate PHP file with CSS header to use that. Is there some other way to do it?

Lets say I want to have that padding set to randomly generated ID $id_1 in CSS and not as inline.

```
$id_1 = generate_function(rand(5,10));
$id_2 = generate_function(rand(5,10));

echo "<div id='".$id_1."' style='padding:20px 10px 0px 10px'>";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you can use some other method to target those divs in CSS, then no or define your styles inline, no.

Comment: @mituw16 Nope, I don't want them to be inline as they are now, I need it in CSS. So there is no other way of doing that? Well, damn. Thx for -1 tho....

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I thought it was a legitimate question. I will however give you an upvote to get back to 0 :)

Comment: @mituw16 yeah that was a general thanks, not aimed at you, sorry if it looked that way. But thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `<style>...</style>` somewhere on the page which you fill with the `$id_1` and `$id_2`. Taking the variables with you to a CSS file is sadly not going to work.

```
<style>
  .<?php echo $id_1; ?> {
    padding:20px 10px 0px 10px
  }

   .<?php echo $id_2; ?> {
    padding:20px 10px 0px 10px
  }
</style>
```

> **Note:** I'm not sure if you can use PHP within `style`-tags! So you might need to echo the complete piece of code including `style`-tags.

Another option is to give each of the divs another `class` and target that `class` with CSS instead of the randomly generated class.

Could you let me know why you want a randomly generated class? It seems like a pretty weird decision, as classes are made so you can target them in your CSS and creating random classes will make it impossible to target them from an external CSS-file.

Comment: Hmmm, thats weird. I know you should not be able to use PHP in <style></style> but it actually works now. When did they change that?

Comment: If you are writing you your styles within a php file, then that should work just fine. That's what I mean by inline styles where you would have to define them in your php file, not some external styles sheet

Comment: @mituw16 Ah, I meant inline by definind it to div itself `<div style="HERE"></div>` Cool, then this works. I'll play with it a bit if it works exactly as I want. If yes, then I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Ok, played with it and it works. Just add to answer that the `<style>` has to be inside the PHP file and an warning from me: CSS names **CAN NOT** start with number... I had to edit my random generator to always set first character to letter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<?php

    $id_1 = "id_".rand(5,10);

    echo $cascading = "<style>#".$id_1."{padding:20px 10px 0px 10px}</style>";

    echo "<div id='".$id_1."'></div>";

?>
```